# "This app isn't compatible with your device anymore." "Device is not certified"

Tags: applications, google-play-store

**TL;DR see this Google support post to complain and upvote:**

**https://support.google.com/android/thread/158332061?hl=en**

I have a OnePlus 7 Pro that is an excellent top end affordable phone. It's been working great for a year until a couple apps I depend on stopped working. One example app is Disney Plus. It will not work at all and will not show up in the Play Store. When I weblink to its Play listing, it says: "This app isn't compatible with your device anymore. Contact the developers for more info."

I pestered the devs and never got anywhere and it looks like a device issue because on this round of searching I found a link that said it's because the "Device is not certified" message in Play settings.

There are many, many posts on this issue, just on the OnePlus forum alone. One discussed a device reflashed from or to a Global version, but I dont think that is my device problem, but also dont know how to verify.

I found a post from XDA that talked about the problem related to not being able to use GApps, but that is not my problem, and inputing the device ID onto Google's site didnt help.

Last post I found discussed it being from the bootloader being unlocked, or that its rooted. Is that really the issue? That would be terrible if rooted devices couldnt use certain apps as popular as Netflix, Disney Plus, PayPal and others.

If it's an issue with OnePlus having their devices certified by Google, is there a way around this. I'm posting to the OnePlus forum, but that's as much as I can do.

Here are a bunch of links for reference. The first one shows the error in Play on a OnePlus brand app. This seems like a recent change from Google's security policies. Second one discusses device model. Third one discusses bootloader and root:

https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/this-app-isnt-compatible-with-your-device-anymore-contact-the-developers-for-more-info.1490603/

https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version-disney.1314553/

https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/netflix-this-app-isnt-compatible-with-your-device-anymore.1377862/

https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/your-device-is-not-compatible-with-this-version.1389536/

https://forums.oneplus.com/threads/your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version.944366/

https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-fix-device-not-certified-by-google-error/

https://forum.fairphone.com/t/unable-to-install-application-since-fairphone-is-not-play-protect-certified/58067

https://komogame.com/en/netflix-blocks-its-app-on-rooted-devices/
"In case your device is rooted, has the bootloader unlocked or the device is not certified by Google, you will not be able to download Netflix through the Play Store" Message only says: your-device-isnt-compatible-with-this-version

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-an-app-on-Android-when-it-says-my-device-is-not-optimized-or-compatible-for-the-app-anymore

[How To Fix - This App Is No Longer Compatible ... - YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uo74AEnlmXQ) Didnt work. Have tried twice.

https://nerdschalk.com/how-to-turn-on-or-off-google-play-protect-on-android/  I cant turn off Play Protect to test this.

https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-install-an-app-on-Android-when-it-says-my-device-is-not-optimized-or-compatible-for-the-app-anymore

https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-fix-This-app-isnt-compatible-with-your-device-anymore-and-Device-is-not-certified-on-an-Android-device

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/how-can-i-fix-this-app-isnt-compatible-with-your-device-anymore-and-device-is-not-certified-on-an-android-device.4417785/

---

It seems my device is Play Protect certified. So I'm leaning toward there being a problem with the bootloader being unlocked, and it being rooted. I use Magisk which is supposed to be systemless, so I doubt that is the problem. And if it is from the unlocked bootloader, only Google or a collection of app developers can fix this.

You can check under Play Store > Settings > About > Play Protect certification.

https://support.google.com/android/answer/10248227?hl=en#zippy=%2Ccant-check-certification-status

https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.html (large list loads slowly) Direct link to csv file: https://storage.googleapis.com/play_public/supported_devices.csv

The Google forum suggest: "If it’s on the list: We’d like more information about your experience. You can start a new thread in the Android Community to help us review the alert."

https://support.google.com/android/search?hl=en&q=play%20protect%20certified&from_promoted_search=true

https://support.google.com/android/thread/153942625?hl=en This suggests "If it’s on the list: We’d like more information about your experience. You can send feedback to help us review the alert." and "If your device uses a custom ROM, register your device." which links to the same "enter device ID" from the XDA post above. I've done that.. dont know how long it takes, but isnt working after a few hours.

https://www.google.com/android/uncertified/?pli=1

Ive added a link to this page in the Google Forum post two links up. Please go there and upvote it and my response. If this doesnt work after a few days, Ill create a new post that can be upvoted specific to this not working.. specific Google thread to upvote:

**https://support.google.com/android/thread/158332061?hl=en**

Comment: Also, it seems like the choice is partially up to the app devs. Many apps are unaffected. Some like PayPal still allow using the app, others tell you to update after a certain type of action, and some wont go past the login screen like Disney Plus.

Comment: The message "Device is not certified" may be related to the [Widevine DRM system](https://www.androidauthority.com/widevine-explained-821935/). Not sure if a Widevine certification can end, but when a streaming app complains about missing certification usually it is about Widevine certification. Other apps like Amazon Video in such a case limit stream to SD content, looks like Disney completely blocks everything.

Comment: @Robert interesting, but its also happening on apps like PayPal Business and AppOps. That may explain the total lack of login on Disney+ vs Hulu and Prime Video working fine.

Comment: If it happens to multiple apps then my guess would be that it is your unlocked bootloader. Google seems to have changed the Google SafetyNet check and now your device does not pass this test. That is the risk of unlocking the bootloader...

Comment: @Robert the main reasons I root are for: using a more sane backup than Google's with zero control (SwiftBackup), ability to customize permissions for more security (AppOps), and to remove bloatware that reduces device performance (AppQuarantine or Disable Application) which also allows me troubleshoot suspicious apps, and firewall (AFWall). These are perfectly good reasons to root, and I would not root if I were able to do these without it. In fact, they make my device more secure, recoverable, and performant.

Comment: I agree with you that root access has a lot of advantages, unfortunately SafetyNet and root don't play well together. Hiding root status has become more and more difficult and it is only a matter time when the last possibility to bypass detection will fail. I already made the decision to stay on the non-root side as I have too many apps that rely on SafetyNet.

Comment: @Robert With the recent removal of even the ability to take a full backup over adb, it does seem that Google is trying to kill functionality (probably in the name of security), however unless they provide these simple, in my view necessary tools mentioned above in some fashion, I believe, if they break that functionality, they will incite a mutiny or an exodus.. and I will be first on that train to LineageOS or whatever. Its a dealbreaker, there is no alternative for me. The use of backups, firewall, permissions and control on any Linux and most other computing systems speaks for itself.

Comment: Ubuntu OS on Android devices is starting to work pretty well, so that may be the next plateau. [This $200 phone can do ANYTHING!!! - Pine64 Pinephone https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCKMxzz9cjs